# Python filter doesn't work as expected

Tags: python

I have the following Python code:

```
a = [1,2,3,'4','55',6]
filter(int,a)
```

The output is:

```
[1, 2, 3, '4', '55', 6]
```

`filter()` is supposed to remove the elements from the provided sequence which translate into false, and return only those elements which translate into true.

I expected the output to be:

```
[1,2,3,6]
```

since these are the only integers in my list.
Am I missing something essential?

Comment: On why your code didn't work: `int` returns an `int` object or raises an exception when input cannot be turned into an `int`, so it will always return a value that evaluates to true.  Filter will filter out anything that evaluates to a "falsy" value, so if you had a `0` in the list it will be filtered out by your filter.

Comment: Please read the documentation about what a language feature does before posting a question about it not working the way you think it does: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter

Comment: @IanAuld  [item for item in iterable if function(item)] is what i think i overlooked; This perfectly answers my question. Yes, you are right, a careful observation goes a long way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) instead:

```
>>> a =[1,2,3,'4','55',6]
>>> filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, int),a)
[1, 2, 3, 6]
```

[`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) will convert each object to integer and since all numbers/strings on the list are non-zero [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) picks them all since they evaluate `True` in boolean context. Instead of that it seems that your goal is to pick objects that are already ints and that can be done with `isinstance`.

Comment: Thanks, Yes, i can get the list i wanted by using isinstance, but i am wondering why the filter(int,<list>) wouldn't work.

Answer (score 2):

`filter()` calls the callable that it is given (`int`) with each item in the iterable and returns those that are Truthy.  Since `int('56')` results in `56`, it is Truthy and is included in the results.  You may want something like this:

```
filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, int), a)
```

or better:

```
[x for x in a if isinstance(x, int)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @niemmi's and @zondo's solution i.e.

```
filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, int), a)
```

Now the question is why filter(int, a) didn't work ?

Filter ultimately call **function(val)** and if this returns false then it filtered it out.

```
>>> int('4')  # Which is returning 4, and its true.
4
```

But if you call this,

```
>>> a =[1,2,3,'4','0',6]
>>> filter(int, a)
[1,2,3,4,6]

>>> a =[1,2,3,'4','55a',6]
>>> filter(int, a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '55a'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[x for x in a if isinstance(x, int)]
```

or

```
filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, int), a)
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit longer way:

- We create a function within which we create a child function.
- The first function that is **"isins"** will take function called inside filter i.e. **isinstance** as an input.
- The code then see that it's returning **check** function and replace **isins(isinstance)** with check.
- Inside child function there is a check for 'True' and 'False' explicitly as bool 1 and 0 are treated in same was as True and Flase hence if we remove this filter then the list will contain numbers as well as bool values and if we put bool filter then 1's and 0's will also get filtered out.
- Ultimately we do the check of func/isinstance to return only those values that are either int or float.

  ```
   def isins(func):
     def check(a):
       if str(a) not in ('True','False'):
         return (func(a,(int,float)))
     return check

   num_list = list(filter(isins(isinstance),a))
   num_list
  ```
- Below code also lets you input datatype explicitly.

  ```
   def isins(func,dt):
     def check(a):
       if str(a) not in ('True','False'):
         return (func(a,dt))
     return check

   num_list = list(filter(isins(isinstance,(int,float)),a))
   num_list
  ```